# How can a iOS app push a local notification after killed when the wifi and cellular is closed?

Tags: ios

I discover an app, called 2n mobile key. I have some doubts about this app. First, I close the wifi, cellular, and switch on the Bluetooth, then I open the app, everything is fine. And then, I kill the app, and open the control center, close the Bluetooth, I got a local push(I have closed the wifi and cellular). I don't know how the app can push the local notification. I doubt the app isn't killed, it is still alive in the background. But, how can it do it?

Comment: how can an app monitor the Bluetooth status and push local notification without living in the background?

Answer (score 0):

The notification feature is called "notification extension", so I think it is kind of alive in the background or we can say alive in the system.

Answer (score 0):

Local Notification should be registered and scheduled after getting permission granted.

Application can schedule local notification for delivery to user **even though wifi or cellular have turned off**. because notification should be delivered to user from iOS (Operating System)

**Documentation**

> **Local notifications give you a way to alert the user at times when your app might not be running**. You schedule local notifications at a time when your app is running either in the foreground or background. After scheduling a notification, the system takes on the responsibility of delivering the notification to the user at the appropriate time. Your app does not need to be running for the system to deliver the notification.

> If your app is not running, or if it is in the background, the system displays local notifications directly to the user. The system can alert the user with an alert panel or banner, with a sound, or by badging your app’s icon. If your app provides a notification content app extension, the system can even use your custom interface to alert the user. If your app is in the foreground when a notification arrives, the system gives your app the opportunity to handle the notification internally.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SchedulingandHandlingLocalNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH5-SW5

Comment: but, how can an app monitor the bluetooth status and push local notification without living in the background.